# Does extraData prop affect on flatlist performance?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to pass `extraData` to my flatlist, but I am woring about its performance, because by passing this prop flatlist will re-rendered on every state update.

So I need to know this will make slow my flatlist or not?

Also I want to know it would be better to pass all state for this prop like: `extraData={this.state}` or would be better to pass just one state like: `extraData={this.state.number}`?

thank befor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extraData prop technically does affect performance since it triggers a rerender of the FlatList items when it changes. However, the doc mentions that :

> If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop, stick it here

So you shouldn't worry too much, implement it if you need it, and if performance becomes a problem, [there are methods and props that you'll be able to use to improve it](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips).

`extraData={this.state.number}` is definitely better than `extraData={this.state}` since you don't necessarily want a rerender of your FlatList items for every render of your parent Component.